# How to run multipe service in a docker container (Apache2 and Supervisor)

Tags: php, linux, docker, apache, ubuntu

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:8.1.5-apache-buster as development

# Install dependencies & extensions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    supervisor \
    cron \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Install php extension
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip \
    exif \
    pcntl \
    intl \
    opcache

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Remove Cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*

# Add UID '1000' to www-data
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# Disable warning
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Enable module dan restart apache nya
RUN a2enmod rewrite && \
    service apache2 restart

# Alias codeception
RUN echo 'alias c="vendor/bin/codecept"' >> /etc/bash.bashrc

# Set Cron
RUN crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * php /var/www/html/yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@app/config/schedule.php 1>> /dev/null 2>&1"; } | crontab -

# Set supervisord
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

The case is the last line: `CMD`, If I disable/remove it, Everything is running ok, also the website can be access, and the console give me a message like this:

```
[Sun Jun 25 16:10:21.982764 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/8.1.5 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sun Jun 25 16:10:21.985657 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

But if those `CMD` is added/active on those Dockerfile, The apache is not running, although the supersivord is running now.

```
2023-06-25 16:13:38,036 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded

2023-06-25 16:13:38,047 INFO supervisord started with pid 1

2023-06-25 16:13:39,088 INFO spawned: 'yii-queue-worker_00' with pid 17

2023-06-25 16:13:39,108 INFO spawned: 'yii-queue-worker_01' with pid 19

2023-06-25 16:13:39,125 INFO spawned: 'yii-queue-worker_02' with pid 21

2023-06-25 16:13:39,145 INFO spawned: 'yii-queue-worker_03' with pid 23

2023-06-25 16:13:40,155 INFO success: yii-queue-worker_00 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Any advise it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Original container image (php:8.1.5-apache-buster) has both ENTRYPOINT("docker-php-entrypoint")  and CMD("apache2-foreground") instructions. In other words, when original container started the main process (pid 1) is a command `docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground`.
When you add a CMD instruction into your docker file, it overwrites the CMD in the original container image and starting process becomes `docker-php-entrypoint /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`, "docker-php-entrypoint" doesn't expect parameters you are passing to it.

To solve your problem, you need to rewrite entrypoint script in such way it can start both apache and supervisor.